# Velodyne HDL-32E to laserscan

Tags: ros, 3d-navigation, pointcloud-to-laserscan, laserscan, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to use gmapping to create the 3D environment for our robot, so I'm assemble a tilting hokuyo laser scanner and using the corresponding driver.

For long term, I plan to use the velodyne laser scanner. The issue is the velodyne package appears to be outputting in pointcloud2 format, instead of laserscan format.

I see options such as using the pointcloud_to_laserscan to create the map. There is also ethzasl package I saw recommended on another post, but we need loop closer.

I basically would like to hear your experiences with using a velodyne lidar for a fast/higher quality 3D map or if the tilting hokuyo would be a viable permanent solution.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89291/velodyne-hdl-32e-to-laserscan/) by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `pointcloud_to_laserscan` is the usual solution for reducing 3D point cloud data for 2D mapping applications.

I've seen papers describing more elaborate schemes, depending on your environment and requirements.

Beware that the Velodyne does not see things nearer than 90cm away. See [this discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/72622/velodyne-fault-readings-at-near-objects/).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2